# Why do erlang builds include .c and .erl source?

Tags: erlang

I am not even a newbie to erlang yet, I am just using RabbitMQ, which is written in Erlang.  After I run configure/make/make install, the **build output directories** have plenty of .c and .erl files.  Is this necessary?  What's the reasoning behind it?
some examples:

- ./lib/erlang/lib/erl_interface-3.7.6/src/misc/show_msg.c
- ./lib/erlang/lib/cosNotification-1.1.18/src/oe_CosNotification.erl

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's necessary. The runtime system of Erlang is written in C, and most of the standard library is written in Erlang.

> What's the reasoning behind it?

What would be the alternative? In order to execute any Erlang code, you need to have the runtime system already started, and so it can't be written in Erlang. It could be written in:

1. Assembly
2. C
3. C++ or some other language
4. Erlang could be executed without a runtime

Assembly is obviously a bad choice: you'd have to rewrite it nearly completely for any new CPU target and it would be much harder to maintain.

C provides excellent performance and portability, and ability to call C code from Erlang would at any rate be required. This is the choice made not only by Erlang, but by Python, Ruby, Perl, etc. as well.

C++ complicates portability (some OSes have C compilers available, but not C++ compilers; quality of C++ compilers varies more); other languages even more so (along with performance, possibly requiring their own runtime, etc.).

The final option would make Erlang a completely different language.

Comment: I meant after I run configure/make/make install, the output directories contain c and erl files.

Comment: @AdamRabung By default, Erlang installs both binaries (*.beam and *.so files in `ebin` and `priv` directories) and source code (the `src` and `c_src` directories) for each library application when you run `make install`.

Comment: @Adam Lindberg - that's definitely what I'm seeing - do you know the reasoning?

Comment: @AdamRabung I guess it's because they prefer a "fuller" installation over a minimal one (you can create a minimal one if it is required by using the release tools bundled with Erlang).